# Visual Studio 2013 Text Editor setting

Tags: visual-studio-2013

I was working and I pressed some keyboard shortcut (not sure what) and now VS shows me dots for space characters. I don't like it. Does anybody know what this setting is called so that I can turn it off?

[image]

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your shortcut was:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>; <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd> (it is a toggle, can be used to switch on/off)

personally, i like this view, as it was set by default in IntelliJ if i remember correctly..
it helps finding unwanted spaces or inconsistent indenting

Comment: Thanks. I find it a bit distracting